# error: no matching function for call to "Queue::Queue()"

Tags: c++, error-handling

So I am trying to call a function in my main.cpp file but I get "error: no matching function for call to 'Queue::Queue()."

Queue.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H
#include <iostream>

class Queue
{
    public:
        Queue(int);
        ~Queue();
        //circular queue methods
        void enqueue(std::string);
        std::string dequeue(); //should send through network, call transmit msg
        void printQueue();
        bool queueIsFull(); //send when full
        bool queueIsEmpty(); //send when empty

    protected:
    private:
        int queueSize;
        int queueHead;
        int queueTail;
        int queueCount;
        std::string *arrayQueue;
};

#endif // QUEUE_H
```

Queue.cpp

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

Queue::Queue(int qs)
{
    queueSize = qs;
    arrayQueue = new string[queueSize];
    queueHead = 0;
    queueTail = 0;
}

Queue::~Queue()
{
    delete[] arrayQueue;
}

void Queue::enqueue(string word)
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        arrayQueue[i] = word;
    }

}

void Queue::printQueue()
{
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        cout<<arrayQueue[j]<<endl;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int userChoice;
    Queue q;

    while(2==2)
    {

        cout<<"======Main Menu======"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Enqueue word"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Dequeue word"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Print queue"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Enqueue sentence"<<endl;
        cout<<"5. Quit"<<endl;
        cin>>userChoice;

        if (userChoice == 1)
        {
            string enqueueWord;
            cout<<"word: ";
            cin>>enqueueWord;
            enqueue(enqueueWord);
        }

        if (userChoice == 2)
        {

        }

        if (userChoice == 3)
        {

        }

        if (userChoice == 4)
        {

        }

        if (userChoice == 5)
        {

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

So to call the function from the header file I did "Queue q;" at the beginning of the int main() and then when I needed to call the function I did "q.enqueue(enqueueWord)." I also tried just doing "Queue::enqueue(enqueueWord), but that also didn't work and I get a different error. I feel like this is an easy fix but I just can't figure it out. Thanks for the help and feel free to ask me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
Queue q;
```

attempts to call the default constructor `Queue::Queue`. However, this constructor has been removed automatically since you explicitly declare a constructor, namely `Queue::Queue(int)`, on your own.

Pass an appropriate argument to `q` when initialized, like

```
Queue q1(42);    // pre-C++11 syntax
Queue q{42};     // available since C++11
```

(**Note:** `42` is only an exemplary value here.)

You could also use default arguments to keep the definition as-is and initialize the object with a default value.

---

Notes:

- Why `while(2==2)`? `while (true)` is the common way.